# Get resource id of attribute of view

Tags: android, android-widget, android-xml

Im creating a custom listview implementation.
This is an instance of my view declaried in xml:

```
<CustomListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_background">
</CustomListView>
```

Is it possible to get the int value of the ’android:listSelector’ resource or any other attribute from my constructor?

```
public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.listSelectorId = ???
}
```

I have tried with this, but it does not return the correct resource id:

```
public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[]{android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground});
    this.selectorResourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: why android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground and not android.R.attr.listSelector ?

Comment: changed to android.R.attr.listSelector, made no difference

Comment: did you try attr.getAttributeResourceValue("android", "listSelector", -1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

attr.getAttributeResourceValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "listSelector", -1) did the trick :)